# Visual Studio 2008: How to view “Advanced” properties in the Properties window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Whenever I click on an object in the Solution Explorer, in the Properties Dialog, all I can see are the "Misc" properties, usually File Name and File Path, but I need to see the "Advanced" section. Under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#, there is a checkbox labeled "Hide advanced members". This was unchecked by default, and I've tried checking + restarting visual studio, unchecking again. Regardless, it's still hidden. I'm not even sure that this relates to Properties, but this was suggested as a solution before. How might I go about fixing this?

EDIT: I'm referring to the properties of files within the project, not the project or solution properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally the case for projects and solutions - the properties window only has the file name and path.

Right click on the solution or project node and select `Properties`. This will bring up the properties pages for them, instead of the properties window (F4).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not quite what I mean. I need the properties of specific items within the project. To be specific, I want to change the build action of a .js file. For whatever reason, I have the 'advanced' properties for every item on my work computer's install of VS2008, but on this one I do not.

Comment: I haven't tried that, but it doesn't seem to be file-specific. If I start a new project, or add a new file to my project (I have tried adding new .js files), there are no advanced properties. At work, every file has advanced properties.

Comment: Ah... are you using an express edition? The features of express and those of pro are very different.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the object in the solution explorer it just shows you the Advanced and Misc properties. If you want to see all the specific properties of the object click on the object itself in the [Design] window.

Answer (score 0):

check the location of folder the items are stored in if they are in folders, they have to be under the project name and not the solution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTuQN.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).